# What is the correct way to pass non-const values to functions that take const parameters in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, constants

I have made a function that is supposed to print an array of arrays for testing purposes. Since I don't want to modify anything in the function itself, I thought it would be good to have a const value and const pointer for the function definition.

```
void test_print(const char*** const array);

/*Some code*/


void test_print(const char*** const command_array){
    int j=0;
    while(command_array[j]!=NULL){
        int k=0;
        while(command_array[j][k]!=NULL){
            printf("%s and %d\n",(command_array[j][k]),j);
            ++k;
        }
        ++j;
    }
}
```

However if I don't call the function by casting my array like this:

```
test_print((const char*** const)command_array);
```

Then I get the error:

```
invalid conversion from 'char***' to 'const char***'
```

So my question is: Am I doing the right thing or is there a another way to do this conversion? Is it true to say that this cast will only make the array const inside the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually safe to cast command_array to `const char*** const`.

Consider this code:

```
void test_print(const char*** const command_array)
{
    // command_array is a constant pointer to a non-constant pointer to a non-constant pointer to a constant char

    // we can easily change one of the non-constant levels
    **command_array = "Hello";
}

void fail()
{
    char command[6] = "hello";
    char *level1 = command;
    char **level2 = &level1;
    char ***level3 = &level2;

    ***level3 = 'j'; // valid; now command holds "jello"

    test_print((const char*** const)level3);

    ***level3 = 'z'; // segfault!
}
```

I believe (meaning I haven't tested this) that `const char* const* const* const` would be safe, though still not implicitly converted.

The last `const` is also not necessary - `const char* const* const*` is the same as `const char* const* const* const`

Comment: It can be implicitly converted in C++ (to `char const* const* const*`), but not in C. I think this is an oversight in C standards.

Comment: Ok, so the function definition should look like:    test_print(const char* const* const*  const* command_array)?

Comment: No, that has an extra `const*`

Comment: On last thing, can you explain to me why: const char* const* const* is the same as const char* const* const* const? For me something has to be be non constant in the first case...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think they are not the same. In the first one, I think it is still possible to modify the 1st level pointer of the array. Whereas the second insures that this 1st level pointer cannot be changed.

Comment: There is a difference, but it is not visible to the caller - see http://pastebin.com/nCTnau53

Answer (score -1):

Be careful here. Your compiler may generate subtly different object code for "const" fields.

"const" is also a way of telling the optimizer that the value will never change. Casting to const something that can change may mislead the compiler and produce unxepected results , especially if you are multi-threading environment.

Comment: The compiler does not assume that a const object never changes, just that code is not allowed to change it.